# Could 'also' be omitted in 'is not restricted to the modal remoteness constructions, but is found also in certain backshift and past time uses'?

Tags: meaning

From Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.87.

> For some speakers, irrealis **were** is not restricted to the modal
> remoteness constructions, but is found also in certain backshift and
> past time uses that bear some resemblance to them:

In summary, 'were'is **both** used in the modal remoteness constructions and backshift and past time uses.

To me, 'restricted' acts the same role as 'only', so omitting 'also' retain the same meaning.

> For some speakers, irrealis **were** is not restricted to the modal
> remoteness constructions, but is found ['also' is deleted] in certain backshift and
> past time uses that bear some resemblance to them:

Is this analysis viable?

Comment: In my opinion, the sentence would be much harder to parse if _also_ were to be omitted.

Comment: Are you seriously questioning the wording in CGEL? It's perfectly clear and grammatically perfect, so why would you want to change it?

Comment: @BillJ I am not questioning, but rather categorizing some usage. For example, in this case, I just want to confirm whether the structure of this sentence is similar to "not only...but also..." due to the word "restricted." Therefore, please do not say that I am questioning. I am earnestly analyzing his sentence.

Comment: Are you asking about grammar, style, or meaning?

Comment: With "also" deleted, I have to return to the previous section of the sentence to determine whether or not "modal remoteness constructions" are a subcategory of the newly described extended usage. With "also" it is clear even before finishing the sentence that the new usage is separate, and that "modal remoteness constructions" are not a subcategory. It makes the sentence significantly easier to parse, as it requires one to hold less information in memory at once to parse it.

Comment: This use of *also* is a good example, per @YonKuma, of one extra word that makes the meaning clearer, even if it could be skipped. You are right that the sentence could skip it.  It's a complicated sentence.

Comment: I suspect the OP mistakenly assumes that ***not only ... but also*** is some kind of "fixed, unbreakable" construction. In fact it's fine to say *X is not only Y - it is Z*. And we're not *obliged* to include words like ***but, also, too, as well,...*** within the "contrastive" element. The cited text includes both ***but*** and ***also*** because doing so makes it much easier to parse, but it would be stylistically "unusual" in this exact context to include ***not only*** in the antecedent (it's an educational / reference textbook, not an advert / promotional puff for irrealis mode! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

> Vitamin E is not limited to nuts and seeds but is found also in certain fruits and vegetables.
>
> Vitamin E is not limited to nuts and seeds; it is found in certain fruits and vegetables as well.

**also** and **as well** are not *necessary* for the sentence to be grammatical.

You would also have available a different punctuation for the second sentence:

> Vitamin E is not limited to nuts and seeds: it is found in certain fruits and vegetables.

Without the conjunction it would be a form of *parataxis*.

Without **also** and **as well** the construction might  be considered quasi-parataxis, as they supply the construction with an additional syntactic guard-rail.